# Should the [shooting] tag be burninated (or synonymized with another tag)?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [shooting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shooting) tag currently has no tag wiki/excerpt.

It's not entirely clear to me what the specific purpose of this tag is that's not covered by existing tags. It seems weirdly specific, and yet vague. Based just on its current use, it seems like it's referring to ranged attacks made with firearms (though "shooting" on its own could potentially refer to attacks with bows and the like as well).

Currently, the tag appears on 2 [shadowrun-sr5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun-sr5) questions, 3 questions with the [savage-worlds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/savage-worlds) and [deadlands-reloaded](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadlands-reloaded) tags, and 1 question tagged with [savage-worlds](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/savage-worlds) (with no further specification). Upon further examination, the 4 Savage Worlds questions were all asked by the [same user](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/3867/texter), who seems to have created the tag by virtue of simply adding it to their questions. They haven't been on the site since February 2019 - so it's not like I can just ask them what the tag's meant for.

The fact that the tag's only been used for Savage Worlds and Shadowrun questions doesn't inherently tell me anything about what the tag's about, other than that this one user made the tag (it's totally unclear whether it's a system-specific concept or not), and that 2 querents asking about Shadowrun SR5 just happened to assume based on the name that the tag fit.

The scope of the tag seems to be entirely covered by the [ranged-attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranged-attack) tag to me, perhaps in conjunction with the [firearms](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firearms) tag where relevant. It's not like we have a tag for "swinging a sword" or something, so it seems strange to have a tag that just refers to a particular kind of ranged attack. This is just an assumption, however.

**Should the [shooting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shooting) tag be deleted, or synonymized with one of the above tags?**

**Alternatively, if the tag shouldn't be removed, when should it be used/what should it be used for?**
(Tag wiki/excerpt suggestions are welcome, if suggesting the tag be kept - this would help clarify the focus of the tag and help differentiate it from the existing tags mentioned above.)

Comment: What harm is it doing, exactly?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast well, if someone posts a question tagged with [tag:shooting] that should be tagged with [tag:ranged-combat] (but isn't tagged with both), then it makes the question harder to find by others. Keeping order among the tags is a good thing ^^

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: In essence, I'm wondering what purpose it's serving to begin with. If it's functionally just serving the same purpose as an existing tag, it may as well be merged (and possibly synonymized). As far as I can tell, it is the same, but I didn't want to make such a move without checking to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Answer (score 4):

I believe we should do nothing with it and leave it be.

Merging it with [firearms](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firearms) seems inappropriate. In Fate, when you're using a bow or a slingshot or darts you're also Shooting but you're definitely not using firearms. [ranged-combat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranged-combat) wouldn't necessarily apply either; just because you're Shooting doesn't mean you're in combat with anyone. I suspect similar stuff is going on for the games already using the tag.

These tags have overlap but not such that [shooting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shooting) is inherently a synonym of either. There's also no specific problem occurring with the tag that calls for us to change things. Let's leave it be.

If/when this does actually cause any kind of problem for Savage Worlds or Shadowrun folks, they can bring up “hey why are we using [shooting](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shooting) when we could be using [ranged-combat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranged-combat)?” or whatever on meta if they'd like to.

Comment: So... What is the [shooting] tag *for*, actually? That has been my fundamental confusion. There's no tag wiki. I suppose I should edit that into my question - if the tag shouldn't be removed, when should it be used/what should it be used for? (EDIT: I also fixed a typo in the question - the tag I meant to reference is [ranged-attack].)

Comment: It's for questions about shooting; that much is probably clear even without a tag wiki. People will know they need it when they do, such as when someone asks a Fate question about the shoot action. I would request you *don't* scope creep the question into that, since "define what this is for" is a big separate request — just post a separate short question requesting someone familiar with its usage add a tag wiki. I suggest also we just leave those users to their own devices.

Comment: I think I got ahead of myself here and made an assumption about what the tag was for, hence my question initially asking whether the tag should be removed. I am more curious what the tag is for in the first place, since it is not at all clear to me. It's not necessarily clear to me that it's a tag referring to a specific concept in those systems, since I don't know what it's for in the first place... I should definitely have asked that first.

Comment: The fact that the tag's only been used for Savage Worlds and Shadowrun questions doesn't inherently tell me anything about what the tag's about, other than that this one user made the tag (it's totally unclear whether it's a system-specific concept or not), and that 2 querents asking about Shadowrun SR5 just happened to assume based on the name that the tag fit. If it *is* a thing relevant to certain systems that I just don't know about, I'm happy to be informed of that. If it's just being used to categorize questions about the same topic [ranged-attack] is for, I'd want to know that too.